# pmr::vector is slower than std::vector

Tags: c++, c++17, benchmarking, stdvector, c++pmr

I wrote a simple  [benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/S8ARu3pDu_XJSf1MLkta0sGq7-E)   to see what is the gain  of using pmr::vector in comparison with std::vector.

In benchmarks , pmr::vector uses n unsynchronized_pool_resource . As upstream a monotonic buffer is used as well.
Have a look in benchmark code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>

static void pmrVector(benchmark::State& state)
{
   constexpr size_t BUF_SIZE = 2048;
   std::pmr::pool_options options;
   options.max_blocks_per_chunk = 4;
   options.largest_required_pool_block = 64;
   
    alignas(8) std::array<char,BUF_SIZE> buffer; // a small buffer on the stack
  
    //std::cout <<options.largest_required_pool_block << std::endl;
   std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource pool{std::data(buffer), std::size(buffer)};
  std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource mem (options,&pool);
  for (auto _ : state) 
  {
    
    std::pmr::vector<char> vec{ &mem };
    for(char i = 'a'; i < 'z';++i)
    {
            
            vec.emplace_back(i);
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(vec);
            
    }

    
  }
}
static void stdVector(benchmark::State& state)
{
   
   for (auto _ : state) 
   {
      std::vector<char> vec{};
      for(char i = 'a'; i < 'z';++i)
      {
            
            vec.emplace_back(i);
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(vec);
            
      }
   }
}
BENCHMARK(pmrVector);
BENCHMARK(stdVector);
```

The pmr::vector is 3x slower that std::vector. Comparing with monotonic buffer seems that the unsynchronized_pool_resource has huge penalty.
Have a look in this benchmark [benchmark monotonic buffer only](https://quick-bench.com/q/2lvtR3zdtsA_ekmBTzzWRQhUsaQ)

Performance comparison using unsynchronized_pool_resource

[image]

Have a look in performance comparison using only monotonic buffer
[image]

Comment: What compiler options (`gcc -O3` I hope?  The default is anti-optimized like MSVC debug mode, which is useless for benchmarking).  What hardware / OS?

Comment: @PeterCordes, I changed the description and I put benchmark data to be clear the performance penalty. I skipped the MVSC performance comparison

Comment: There is quite a bit of initializations taking place in pmrVector, of data that should not be created on every call, maybe? I'm thinking of the memory pool created inside the loop.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy, your are right. That I had in mind as well. The creation of the vector has significant penalty as well. Put this outside for outer loop , the gain is 1.2x. But still not enough [https://quick-bench.com/q/S8X_9MGYTRwewqYKVMiyF_TiqO0]

Comment: pmr is useful when you have lots of data and some work being done.  I think that right now, you are only measuring the difference in setup times.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy, yes .I just put elements in the vectors.

Comment: pmr is type-erasure for allocators. It isn't useful when you have one allocation strategy.

Answer (score 3):

You have to be very careful of what you are timing really.
I did some reasonable changes to your test and I can see an improvement, probably mostly coming from not needing to use the system-wide allocation.
(Advantages of PMR go beyond this.)

1. Test more elements
2. Since you need to test more elements, don't use a stack buffer: use a single allocation and don't measure it.
3. Reset the memory resource, otherwise you are making a bad use of the memory resource by overflowing the monotonic resource simply because the loop is tested repeatedly.

With all this changes I get to a more expected results.
https://quick-bench.com/q/ylppu2cug3S25q1xGrRCGdTEjd4

[image: bench]

important part of the code:

```
static void pmrVector(benchmark::State& state)
{
  constexpr size_t BUF_SIZE = 1000000000;
  std::pmr::pool_options options;
  options.max_blocks_per_chunk = 40;
  options.largest_required_pool_block = 640;
    
  char* buffer = new char[BUF_SIZE];
  std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource pool{buffer, BUF_SIZE};
  std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource mem (options,&pool);
  for (auto _ : state) 
  {
    {
      std::pmr::vector<char> vec{ &mem };
      for(int i = 0; i != 100000000; ++i)
      {
            
            vec.emplace_back('a');
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(vec);
            
      }
    }
    mem.release();
    pool.release();
  }
  delete[] buffer;
}
```

Comment: Just to point out use a buffer has nothing to do with PMR allocator. it can as well being a static typed allocator.

Comment: @appleapple of course, there are many ways to use a buffer for allocation. PMR just provides one possible design that works out of the box currently. Thrust MR provides statically typed allocators that do the same (but without the virtual call)